# Is it possible to get the data from Facebook's Live Stream plugin out via the Graph API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We're thinking of making use of the Facebook Live Stream social plugin for our site ([example here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream)), but I wanted to know if it was possible to access this data via the Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/ID/feed

Where ID is the ID of the feed you wish to obtain.  In the example you linked:

https://graph.facebook.com/113869198637480/feed

You can do this with FQL:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20actor_id,%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20=%20YOUR_APP_ID%20limit%2050

Comment: And where did you get the ID from?

Comment: The ID is the feed which you wish to get the data from.  (Application, User, Event, etc...)

Comment: No, because I have my App ID in the URL to get the live stream box, but when I put that same App ID into the above link it doesn't work. I'm not looking to get the data from my App or an event etc. I know how to do that. I want to know how to get the data from the Live Stream box that I've created. If there is an ID for it then great, but I can't find that ID anywhere.

Comment: I see the problem now.  Just came across this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

Comment: Isn't that a user's stream, rather than a Live Stream? The Live Stream doesn't seem to post that stuff anywhere, even to the wall of the app who's ID is being stored, except if someone checks the box marked "post to facebook"

Comment: See edits on answer.  The link above will show the fields you can query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Shame there's nothing in the Graph API